# Selecting Tabbar item in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

My app has #hashtags that can be selected.

We have only 3 tabs in our TabBar, MainVC, ProfileVC and TagVC. TagDetailVC is typically accessed via TagVC.

When the user selects a tag, she will be directed to TagDetailViewController.

**EDIT** I hooked up a tabbarController on storyboard.

Right now I have this:

```
TagDetailViewController *dest = [[TagDetailViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nav = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];
[nav pushViewController:dest animated:YES];
```

However, all I am seeing right now is TagVC. I placed a log a statement in viewDidLoad in TagDetailVC and it did not show.

For the record, this is how my story board is organized:

```
TabBarController -> NavigationVC -> MainVC ... 
                 -> NavigationVC -> ProfileVC ...  
                 -> NavigationVC -> TagVC -> TagDetailVC
```

I am interested to have the tabBar select TagVC and then push TagDetailVC onto the navigationController of TagVC. The behavior that I am expecting when a user presses a tag is: 
1. Tab is selected at TagVC
2. TagDetailVC is pushed onto the NavigationVC of TagVC.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: UINavigationController *nav = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];
[nav pushViewController:dest animated:YES]; instead directly write TagDetailViewController *dest = [[TagDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TagDetailViewController" bundle:nil];[self.navigationController pushViewController:dest animated:YES]

Comment: What's wrong with creating a tab bar in IB, and put navcontrollers containing regular detailviewcontrollers in it? Maybe I misunderstood, but that seems to be your goal and it's a normal structure for an app and can be done without any special code.

Comment: @Manobar that doesn't change the tab index. If I have code to change the tabIndex, the push would be invalid

Comment: @HenrikErlandsson yes that's exactly what I have done. My goal is to change tab and display the right view

Comment: My point was that you can drag and drop navcontrollers and view controllers in IB, and Cocoa would automatically show the viewcontroller correctly when you press the tab or programmatically change tab. If you want to override this standard behavior, you can push any view controller at all onto any tab's navcontroller, as per some of the answers below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below method for `UITabbarController`:

```
  [tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];
```

According to my understanding this would be: `NavigationVC -> TagVC`

Now use `NSNotification`, and push view controller to `TagDetailVC`.

Hope this might help you to achieve your requirement.

Comment: can you explain why NSNotification is necessary?

Comment: when you select a tab in tabbarcontroller it will lead you to specific navigation controller assigned to that index (which is TagVC in your case). But in your requirement you want to move one step further to move to next VC (TagDetailVC). So for that you can use NSNotification which is implemented in TagVC, and that will pushViewController to TagDetailVC. Let me know if you are getting my point or not.

Answer (score 0):

I would attempt something like this (pseudocode):

```
on tagTapped
    tagDetailViewController = (alloc, config TagDetailVC)
    (tab controller).viewControllers[2].viewControllers = @[ new TagVC, tagDetailViewController ] ;
    (tab controller).selectedIndex = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow this is working.

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = TAB_INDEX_TAGS;
UINavigationController *nav = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];
[nav pushViewController:dest animated:YES];
```